# Chakra ui changes to dark mode when the system setting app mode is set to dark mode, but I don't want dark mode on the web app yet

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui, darkmode

Dark mode makes the app looks ugly, how do I disable dark mode feature on chakra UI (React Js)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to set the `useSystemColorMode` prop to `false`, so chakraUI knows not to use `systemColorMode`

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/features/color-mode#add-colormodescript

```
// theme.js

// 1. import `extendTheme` function
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

// 2. Add your color mode config
const config = {
  initialColorMode: 'light',
  //  If true, your app will change color mode based on the user's system preferences.
  useSystemColorMode: false,
}

// 3. extend the theme
const theme = extendTheme({ config })

export default theme
```